# CORS Error in React App Deployed on AWS Amplify

Tags: spring-boot, cors, aws-amplify

I am receiving the below messages in my Google Chrome console when running my React application which is deployed to AWS Amplify. I click on the 'Login/Signup' link of my React app, which in turn generates a GET request. The Spring Boot Java backend is also deployed to AWS Amplify. The first message which appears in the Chrome console says

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at *backend_URL_on_AWS_Amplify* from origin *frontend_URL_on_AWS_Amplify* has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The next message in my console says

> GET *backend_URL_on_AWS_Amplify* net::ERR_FAILED

On the network tab of the developer tools, I can see the failed GET requests. On the Headers tab I see the referrer policy reads: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin". Accept reads: "application/json/ text/plain, */*". There is nothing on the response tab.

Here are the lines where I use Tanstack-query to make the call to the backend, this is the call that is generating the CORS errors

```js
const { data: empList } = useQuery("employerList", () => {
  return axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL + "/employer/list");
});
```

There are no CORS errors occurring when testing the backend and frontend locally on my machine.

I also put the above custom headers in a customHttp.yml file, placed the file at the root of the backend and frontend source directories, pushed the code to the backend and frontend repositories and redeployed to AWS Amplify, but the CORS errors continue.

In the Spring Boot Java backend I placed the CrossOrigin annotation above the class declaration of each controller. Here is an example

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class ApplicationController {
```

I also placed the CrossOrigin annotation above the application class declaration as shown here

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JobsearchApplication {
```

**What I expected to happen:** I expected that I could click the Login/Signup link of my React app which is deployed on AWS Amplify and that the get request that is generated would run successfully, thereby populating the dropdown list of employers which the employers from the database and that I would be able to register user accounts in the system and login as a registered user.

The contents of the application.properties file of the backend are

```properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
spring.mvc.cors.enabled=true
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-origins=*
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-methods=*
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-headers=*
spring.mvc.cors.allow-credentials=true
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

I have also included a CorsConfig class in the application as follows

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[Network tab showing request/response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naYa5.png)

[Chrome console error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbCs8.png)

Comment: FYI you cannot add `allow-credentials=true` with `allowed-origins=*`

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the **response** for your `/employer/list` request. Does it respond with a 200 status? What **exactly** are the **response headers**? Is there a response body at all and if so, is it what you expect?

Comment: There is no response body at all there is no http response code. I am going to try to post a screenshot of what I see. I am sorry I am new to stack overflow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There has to be some sort of response otherwise it wouldn't be able to tell you there's missing CORS headers. Screenshots would be helpful, thanks

Comment: I just did some test requests against the URLs in your screenshot and the request for `/employer/list` responds with a 301 redirect to `/employer/list/` (trailing slash). Following the redirect responds with a 404 so there's something wrong with your backend configuration even before CORS comes into it

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot to the post, but it changed it to a link, if you follow the link it will show you what the network tab looks like in google chrome. "Network tab showing request/response"

Comment: Thank you Phil I will look into this issue with the backend configuration. I appreciate your help.